# How to Hide some document type from document type as per community (Umbraco)

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I want to hide some document type in setting -> document type. As per community wise. Is this possible to get this with some event handler or via any package or some custom code.

**e.g :There is one document type News and there 2 community i want to give this document to community1 which is in Admin and hide from community2.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution. I can get the list of all the document type by using 
**TreeControllerBase.TreeNodesRendering** event and we can remove particular or remove all the node also.

Thank you.